# Rendering in discrete layers, then composited

Tags: opengl-es, webgl, three.js

In my project, I know have 3 discreet layers.

1. Background
2. Midground
3. Foreground

Each of these layers could potentially have vastly different unit scales and potentially overlapping geometry. But I don't want them to render as if they occupy the same "space". I want them to render in their logical layer order, not their order in 3D space.

For example, lets say the **Background** is a narrow tube, 10 units in radius, that I put over the camera to achieve a tunnel like effect. I then want to put a large cube as the **Foreground**, 100 units on each side, in the scene far from the camera.

In this scenario, the cube and the tunnel intersect and obscure each other. I'm looking for a way to render the entire tunnel, and then render an entire cube, and then put that rendered cube on top of the rendered tunnel. And I want any alpha transparency in textures/shaders in that cube to be cleanly composite, showing the rendered tunnel behind transparent pixels.

So:

1. Am I describing a technique or feature that exists? If so, what's that called?
2. Can WebGL do this?
3. Can three.js do this?
4. Will this cause any massive performance drops over rendering a whole frame in one go?
5. How would structure my rendering in three.js to set this up?

*Still new the `*GL` graphics programming, so sorry if my vocabulary isn't accurate. Pedantic vocabulary corrections are appreciated, as it will help me google!*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I managed this one, after some reverse engineering of this example:
http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_rtt.html

Basically

```
renderer.autoClear = false;
```

Then instead of rendering one scene like this:

```
render: function() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

I manually clear before rendering multiple scenes:

```
render: function() {
  renderer.clear()
  renderer.render(background, camera);
  renderer.render(midground,  camera);
  renderer.render(foreground, camera);
}
```

Still not totally sure of performance implications, however.

Answer (score 1):

First off you could render the 3 different canvases and just set their z-index and position so they overlap and the browser will composite them.

If you want to do it all in 1 canvas then basically you just clear the depth buffer after drawing some stuff.

```
drawStuffInBack();

// clear the depth (and stencil buffers)
gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | gl.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

drawStuffInMiddle();

// clear the depth (and stencil buffers)
gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | gl.STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

drawStuffInFront();
```

Comment: There is an API for that: `renderer.clear( false, true, true );`.

Comment: There may be an API for that in ThreeJS but in WebGL (which was part 2 of the original question) this is how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a working example that has a `VisualLayers` class for managing any number of layers, and it uses the `renderer.autoClear = false` technique and clearing-depth technique as Alex Waynes and gman's answers hinted at.

This approach is nice because `renderOrder` of objects is not being modified (that's another approach) and thus will not introduce other issues.

Try playing with the options in the UI to see what it does:

```js
// @ts-check

////////////////////////
// LAYER SYSTEM
////////////////////////

/** @typedef {{name: string, backingScene: THREE.Scene, order: number}} Layer */

class VisualLayers {
    /**
     * @type {Array<Layer>}
     * @private
     */
    __layers = [];

    constructor(
        /** @private @type {THREE.WebGLRenderer} */ __renderer,
        /** @private @type {typeof THREE.Scene} */ __Scene = THREE.Scene
    ) {
        this.__renderer = __renderer;
        this.__Scene = __Scene;
    }

    defineLayer(/** @type {string} */ name, /** @type {number=} */ order = 0) {
        const layer = this.__getLayer(name);

        // The default layer always has order 0.
        const previousOrder = layer.order;
        layer.order = name === "default" ? 0 : order;

        // Sort only if order changed.
        if (previousOrder !== layer.order)
            this.__layers.sort((a, b) => a.order - b.order);

        return layer;
    }

    /**
     * Get a layer by name (if it doesn't exist, creates it with default order 0).
     * @private
     */
    __getLayer(/** @type {string} */ name) {
        let layer = this.__layers.find((l) => l.name === name);

        if (!layer) {
            layer = { name, backingScene: new this.__Scene(), order: 0 };
            layer.backingScene.autoUpdate = false;
            this.__layers.push(layer);
        }

        return layer;
    }

    removeLayer(/** @type {string} */ name) {
        const index = this.__layers.findIndex((l) => {
            if (l.name === name) {
                l.backingScene.children.length = 0;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        });

        if (index >= 0) this.__layers.splice(index, 1);
    }

    hasLayer(/** @type {string} */ name) {
        return this.__layers.some((l) => l.name === name);
    }

    /** @readonly */
    get layerCount() {
        return this.__layers.length;
    }

    addObjectToLayer(
        /** @type {THREE.Object3D} */ obj,
        /** @type {string | string[]} */ layers
    ) {
        if (Array.isArray(layers)) {
            for (const name of layers) this.__addObjectToLayer(obj, name);
            return;
        }

        this.__addObjectToLayer(obj, layers);
    }

    addObjectsToLayer(
        /** @type {THREE.Object3D[]} */ objects,
        /** @type {string | string[]} */ layers
    ) {
        for (const obj of objects) {
            this.addObjectToLayer(obj, layers);
        }
    }

    /** @private @readonly */
    __emptyArray = Object.freeze([]);

    /** @private */
    __addObjectToLayer(
        /** @type {THREE.Object3D} */ obj,
        /** @type {string} */ name
    ) {
        const layer = this.__getLayer(name);
        const proxy = Object.create(obj, {
            children: { get: () => this.__emptyArray }
        });
        layer.backingScene.children.push(proxy);
    }

    removeObjectFromLayer(
        /** @type {THREE.Object3D} */ obj,
        /** @type {string | string[]} */ nameOrNames
    ) {
        if (Array.isArray(nameOrNames)) {
            for (const name of nameOrNames) {
                const layer = this.__layers.find((l) => l.name === name);
                if (!layer) continue;
                this.__removeObjectFromLayer(obj, layer);
            }
            return;
        }

        const layer = this.__layers.find((l) => l.name === nameOrNames);
        if (!layer) return;
        this.__removeObjectFromLayer(obj, layer);
    }

    /** @private */
    __removeObjectFromLayer(
        /** @type {THREE.Object3D} */ obj,
        /** @type {Layer} */ layer
    ) {
        const children = layer.backingScene.children;
        const index = children.findIndex(
            (proxy) => /** @type {any} */ (proxy).__proto__ === obj
        );

        if (index >= 0) {
            children[index] = children[children.length - 1];
            children.pop();
        }
    }

    removeObjectsFromAllLayers(/** @type {THREE.Object3D[]} */ objects) {
        for (const layer of this.__layers) {
            for (const obj of objects) {
                this.__removeObjectFromLayer(obj, layer);
            }
        }
    }

    render(
        /** @type {THREE.Camera} */ camera,
        /** @type {(layerName: string) => void} */ beforeEach,
        /** @type {(layerName: string) => void} */ afterEach
    ) {
        for (const layer of this.__layers) {
            beforeEach(layer.name);
            this.__renderer.render(layer.backingScene, camera);
            afterEach(layer.name);
        }
    }
}

//////////////////////
// VARS
//////////////////////

let camera, stats, geometry, material, object, object2, root;
let time = 0;
/** @type {THREE.Scene} */
let scene;
/** @type {THREE.WebGLRenderer} */
let renderer;
/** @type {VisualLayers} */
let visualLayers;
const clock = new THREE.Clock();
const greenColor = "#27ae60";
const options = {
    useLayers: true,
    showMiddleBox: true,
    rotate: true,
    layer2Order: 2
};

//////////////////////
// INIT
//////////////////////

~(function init() {
    setup3D();
    renderLoop();
})();

////////////////////////////////
// SETUP 3D
////////////////////////////////

function setup3D() {
    const container = document.createElement("div");
    container.id = "container";
    document.body.appendChild(container);

    // CAMERA
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        70,
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        1,
        10000
    );
    camera.position.x = 0;
    camera.position.z = 500;
    camera.position.y = 0;

    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    // RENDERERS

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, alpha: true });
    renderer.setClearColor(0x111111);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // LAYERS

    visualLayers = new VisualLayers(renderer);
    // Layers don't have to be defined. Adding an object to a layer will
    // automatically create the layer with order 0. But let's define layers with
    // order values.
    visualLayers.defineLayer("layer1", 1);
    visualLayers.defineLayer("layer2", 2);
    visualLayers.defineLayer("layer3", 3);

    // LIGHTS

    const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.5);
    directionalLight.position.set(300, 0, 300);
    scene.add(directionalLight);
    visualLayers.addObjectToLayer(directionalLight, [
        "layer1",
        "layer2",
        "layer3"
    ]);

    const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.4);
    scene.add(ambientLight);
    visualLayers.addObjectToLayer(ambientLight, ["layer1", "layer2", "layer3"]);

    // GEOMETRY

    root = new THREE.Object3D();
    scene.add(root);

    geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(100, 100, 100);
    material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: greenColor,
        transparent: false,
        opacity: 1
    });

    object = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    root.add(object);
    visualLayers.addObjectToLayer(object, "layer1");
    object.position.y = 80;
    object.position.z = -20;
    // object.rotation.y = -Math.PI / 5

    object2 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    object.add(object2);
    visualLayers.addObjectToLayer(object2, "layer2");
    object2.position.y -= 80;
    object2.position.z = -20;
    object2.rotation.y = -Math.PI / 5;

    const object3 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    object2.add(object3);
    visualLayers.addObjectToLayer(object3, "layer3");
    object3.position.y -= 80;
    object3.position.z = -20;
    object3.rotation.y = -Math.PI / 5;

    // GUI

    const pane = new Tweakpane({
        title: "VisualLayers"
    });
    pane.addInput(options, "useLayers", { label: "use layers" });
    pane.addInput(options, "showMiddleBox", { label: "show middle box" });
    pane.addInput(options, "rotate");
    pane
        .addInput(options, "layer2Order", {
            label: "layer2 order",
            options: {
                0: 0,
                2: 2,
                4: 4
            }
        })
        .on("change", () => visualLayers.defineLayer("layer2", options.layer2Order));

    // STATS
    // SEE: https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js

    stats = new Stats();
    stats.domElement.style.position = "absolute";
    stats.domElement.style.left = "0px";
    stats.domElement.style.top = "0px";
    stats.setMode(0);
    document.body.appendChild(stats.domElement);
}

//////////////////////
// RESIZE
//////////////////////

(window.onresize = function (event) {
    camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
})();

//////////////////////
// RAF RENDER LOOP
//////////////////////

function render() {
    stats.begin();

    if (options.rotate) {
        time += clock.getDelta();
        object.rotation.y += 0.02;
        root.rotation.y = Math.PI / 2 + (Math.PI / 6) * Math.sin(time * 0.001);
    }

    object2.visible = options.showMiddleBox;

    if (options.useLayers) {
        scene.updateWorldMatrix(true, true);
        renderer.autoClear = false;
        renderer.clear();
        visualLayers.render(camera, beforeEachLayerRender, afterEachLayerRender);
    } else {
        renderer.autoClear = true;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    stats.end();
}

function renderLoop() {
    render();
    requestAnimationFrame(renderLoop);
}

function beforeEachLayerRender(layer) {}
function afterEachLayerRender(layer) {
    renderer.clearDepth();
}
```

```css
html,
body,
#container {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

canvas {
    background: transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tweakpane@1.5.5/dist/tweakpane.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/stats.js/r11/Stats.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/three@0.121.1/build/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="//unpkg.com/postprocessing@6.17.4/build/postprocessing.js"></script>
```

([example on codepen](https://codepen.io/trusktr/pen/fba5c480de9f08357152dad3c79b378b?editors=0010))